# Converting Java to Perl (BigInteger)

Tags: java, perl, biginteger

I am trying converting java code to perl code.

```
BigInteger(byte[] val)
```

[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])%22%20target=%22_blank)
This is Java BigInteger constructor.

Perl Math::BigInt doesn't have a same constructor.
But I should make it and the same Java BigInteger constructor.

How can i do following two code same output.
Is it simple? or very difficult?
I have no idea..

**Java**

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class Hash 
{ 
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception 
    { 
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); 
        String plain = "abcd1234"; 
        BigInteger digest = new BigInteger(md5.digest(plain.getBytes("UTF-8"))); 

        System.out.println( digest.abs() ); 
    } 
}
```

**Perl**

```perl
use Digest::MD5 'md5_hex'; 
use Math::BigInt; 

my $plain = "abcd1234"; 
my $digest = Math::BigInt::->from_hex(md5_hex $plain); 
print $digest, "\n";
```